# Why am I getting outdated values out of JSON files discord,js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've made a simple database of the number of times a user was hugged using a command. I use a JSON file to store it, but whenever I ask for the amount of hugs for some user, it gives me an outdated value (even tho it's saved correctly in the JSON file). I've tried logging the amount of hugs when someone hugs someone else, and then it's correct, but whenever I use the command made for getting the amount of hugs, it gives outdated values. I've made the command that gives the amount of hugs an user received by copying the command that did the same with pats, just changing the variables. For pats it works perfectly, but for hugs it gives outdated values. Also, whenever I read that one JSON file, it lags the bot, or even times it out. I've even made a new file, but nothing changed. The only moment it gives updated values is when I restart the bot, then it gives the same values to the moment when I restart the bot again. Any ideas of why this could be happening?

My code for checking the amount of hugs is this:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
//const ms = require("ms");
let hugs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./hugs.json", "utf-8"));

module.exports = {
    name: 'hugsamount',
    description: "The bot will view the amount of hugs the mentioned user has",
    execute(message, args){
        var huggedone = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first());
        //var patter = message.author;
        if(!huggedone) {
            huggedone = message.author
            if(!hugs[huggedone.id])hugs[huggedone.id] = {
                hugs: 0
            };
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs < 1){
                message.reply(`you have never been hugged so far <:blobcry:749322720554254348>`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs === 1){
                message.reply(`you have been hugged once so far`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs > 1){
                message.reply(`you have been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far`);
            };
        } else
        if(huggedone.id === message.author.id) {
            if(!hugs[huggedone.id])hugs[huggedone.id] = {
                hugs: 0
            };
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs < 1){
                message.reply(`you have never been hugged so far <:blobcry:749322720554254348>`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs === 1){
                message.reply(`you have been hugged once so far`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs > 1){
                message.reply(`you have been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far`);
            };
        } else {
            if(!hugs[huggedone.id])hugs[huggedone.id] = {
                hugs: 0
            };
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs < 1){
                message.reply(`<@${huggedone.id}> has never been hugged so far <:blobcry:749322720554254348>`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs === 1){
                message.reply(`<@${huggedone.id}> has been hugged once so far`);
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs > 1){
                message.reply(`<@${huggedone.id}> has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far`);
            };
        }
        console.log(`Hugs amount = ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs}`)
        console.log(`Hugged one = ${huggedone}`)
    }
}
```

and for hugging (and updating the file) is this:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
//const ms = require("ms");
let hugs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./hugs.json", "utf-8"));

module.exports = {
    name: 'hug',
    description: "The bot will hug the mentioned user",
    execute(message, args){
        var huggedone = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first());
        var randomhugemote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        if(!huggedone) return message.reply('please mention the one who should be hugged');
        if(huggedone.id === message.author.id) { // or if huggedone = message.mentions.members.first(), then use if(huggedone.id === message.author.id)
            if(!hugs[huggedone.id])hugs[huggedone.id] = {
                hugs: 0
            };
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs < 1) {
                if(randomhugemote == "1") {
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have never been hugged by someone else before <:blobcry:749322720554254348>) <:viprinhug:746426111847694417>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 1')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "2"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have never been hugged by someone else before <:blobcry:749322720554254348>) <:cattohug:746651044502569041>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 2')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "3"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have never been hugged by someone else before <:blobcry:749322720554254348>) <:foxlove:746426484649885757>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 3')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "4"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have never been hugged by someone else before <:blobcry:749322720554254348>) <:blobheart:746650772296564799>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 4')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "5"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have never been hugged by someone else before <:blobcry:749322720554254348>) <:pandaheart:750407498342596689>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 5')
                };
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs == 1){
                if(randomhugemote == "1") {
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else once so far) <:viprinhug:746426111847694417>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 1')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "2"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else once so far) <:cattohug:746651044502569041>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 2')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "3"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else once so far) <:foxlove:746426484649885757>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 3')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "4"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else once so far) <:blobheart:746650772296564799>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 4')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "5"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else once so far) <:pandaheart:750407498342596689>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 5')
                };
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs > 1){
                if(randomhugemote == "1") {
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far) <:viprinhug:746426111847694417>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 1')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "2"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far) <:cattohug:746651044502569041>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 2')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "3"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far) <:foxlove:746426484649885757>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 3')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "4"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far) <:blobheart:746650772296564799>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 4')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "5"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged yourself, but it won't count towards your amount of hugs (you have been hugged by someone else a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far) <:pandaheart:750407498342596689>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 5')
                };
            }
        } else {
            if(!hugs[huggedone.id])hugs[huggedone.id] = {
                hugs: 0
            };

            hugs[huggedone.id].hugs++;

            fs.writeFile("./hugs.json", JSON.stringify(hugs), err => {
                if (err) console.log(err)
            });

            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs === 1){
                if(randomhugemote == "1") {
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged once so far <:viprinhug:746426111847694417>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 1')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "2"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged once so far <:cattohug:746651044502569041>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 2')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "3"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged once so far <:foxlove:746426484649885757>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 3')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "4"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged once so far <:blobheart:746650772296564799>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 4')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "5"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged once so far <:pandaheart:750407498342596689>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 5')
                };
            } else
            if(hugs[huggedone.id].hugs > 1){
                if(randomhugemote == "1") {
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far <:viprinhug:746426111847694417>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 1')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "2"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far <:cattohug:746651044502569041>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 2')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "3"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far <:foxlove:746426484649885757>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 3')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "4"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far <:blobheart:746650772296564799>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 4')
                };
                if(randomhugemote == "5"){
                    message.reply(`you have successfully hugged <@${huggedone.id}>, who has been hugged a total of ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs} times so far <:pandaheart:750407498342596689>`);
                    console.log('Random hug emote = 5')
                };
            }
            console.log(`Hugs amount = ${hugs[huggedone.id].hugs}`)
            console.log(`hugged one = ${huggedone}`)
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON file is saving correctly, the only problem is in reading it.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @domenikk ok, I've updated the post

Comment: Your code that checks only loads the file when it starts; it'll never re-read the file unless you tell it to. :)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I have moved the `let hugs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./hugs.json", "utf-8"));` into `module.exports` and it solved the problem with lag and outdated values. I am just confused about the fact that I have the exact same code with just different values and it works perfectly (I've now changed that other code too just to be sure).

Comment: This is random, but you can shorten `message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first())` to just `message.mentions.members.first()`, as it will already return a `GuildMember` object